# Is PAM an appropriate method to authenticate a user on MacOS

Tags: macos, pam

I am trying to authenticate a user on MacOS using PAM with the following code:

```
#include <security/pam_appl.h>

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

static int PamCallbackFn( int num_msg,
            const struct pam_message **msg,
            struct pam_response **resp,
            void *appdata_ptr )
{
    printf("PamCallbackFn num_msg=%d:\n", num_msg );
    for ( int idx = 0; idx < num_msg; ++ idx )
    {
        printf(
            "\tPrompt type %d for '%s'\n", 
            msg[idx]->msg_style,
            msg[idx]->msg );
    }

    assert( num_msg == 1 );
    struct pam_response *response = 
        (struct pam_response *)malloc( sizeof( struct pam_response ) );
    response->resp = strdup( "fhtest" );
    response->resp_retcode = 0;

    *resp = response;
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    struct pam_conv Callback;
    Callback.conv = PamCallbackFn;
    Callback.appdata_ptr = 0;

    printf("Calling pam_start()...\n");

    pam_handle_t *AuthHandle = 0;
    int Result = 
        pam_start(
            "test",     // Client program name
            "fhtest",   // User name
            &Callback,
            &AuthHandle );
    if ( Result != PAM_SUCCESS )
    {
        printf(
            "pam_start() returned %d (%s)\n",
            Result,
            pam_strerror( AuthHandle, Result ) );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Calling pam_authenticate()...\n");
    Result = pam_authenticate( AuthHandle, PAM_SILENT );
    if ( Result != PAM_SUCCESS )
    {
        printf(
            "pam_authenticate() returned %d (%s)\n",
            Result,
            pam_strerror( AuthHandle, Result ) );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Calling pam_acct_mgmt()...\n");
    Result = pam_acct_mgmt( AuthHandle, 0 );
    if ( Result != PAM_SUCCESS )
    {
        printf(
            "pam_acct_mgmt() returned %d (%s)\n",
            Result,
            pam_strerror( AuthHandle, Result ) );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Success !\n");
    pam_end( AuthHandle, Result );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The compile and run commands on MacOS are:

```
clang pamtest.c -lpam
sudo ./a.out
```

However when the code is run on MacOS the output is:

```
Calling pam_start()…
Calling pam_authenticate()…
pam_authenticate() returned 9 (authentication error)
```

No attempt is made to by pam to call **PamCallbackFn()** to supply the password.

If the same code is compiled and run on **Ubuntu**, authentication is successful and I get the following output:

```
Calling pam_start()…
Calling pam_authenticate()…
PamCallbackFn num_msg=1
    Prompt type 1 for 'Password: '
Calling pam_acct_mgmt()…
Success !
```

The user account **fhtest** exists on both **MacOS** and **Ubuntu**. I can login manually using this account to both computers.

There is no specific pam service file for "test" in `/etc/pam.d` (first argument to the `pam_start` call).  In this case pam should fall back to using `/etc/pam.conf`.  The file `/etc/pam.conf` exists on the Ubuntu computer, but consists only of comments.  The file `/etc/pam.conf` does not exist on the MacOS computer.  Creating the file `/etc/pam/conf` on the MacOS computer similar to the one on the Ubuntu computer does not fix the problem.

What I am looking for is a working example of how to authenticate a user with a *UserName* and *Password* on MacOS.  The solution should be usable from a background service or daemon.

Comment: In cases like this, one possibility is use a debugger and stepping into the pam_ functions, so that you can see which decisions that library takes. The other is to look at the PAM library source code.

Comment: I had a quick look at the Apple pam_modules source (https://opensource.apple.com/source/pam_modules/pam_modules-159/), but nothing obvious stood out.  However this has given me some pointers for further research.

Comment: PAM is an interface for authentication tasks and it does not make the authentication by itself (for example it can delegate the authentication to a remote Kerberos or LDAP server, or to a local login system). The configuration at system level decides how authentication must be done for each service. Your service "test" might be misconfigured on your MacOS system.

Comment: @user8034222 - thank you for you comment.  I get the fact that PAM is the interface to the authentication system.  The MacOS installation is a clean install and PAM stack hasn't been changed since install.  I'm reasonably sure we can rule out a misconfigured PAM stack.  Can you explain what you mean by "configuration at system level decides how authentication must be done for each service"?

Comment: For example on my system I have configuration files /etc/pam.d/<service> (service being cups, ppp, etc.), that indicate how PAM should redirect the authentication for each service.

Comment: @user803422 - There isn't a specific service file for "test" in the /etc/pam.d/ folder.  This is true for both the MacOS computer and the Ubuntu computer I am using for testing.  In this situation pam should fall back to /etc/pam.conf.  /etc/pam.conf is present on the Ubuntu computer, but just contains a set of comments.  /etc/pam.conf is not present on the MacOS computer.  Creating a similar /etc/pam.conf file on the MacOS computer to the one found on the Ubuntu computer does not fix the issue.

Comment: @user803422 - Changing the first argument to pam_start() to "login" allows the code sample to authenticate a user on both Ubuntu and MacOS.  If you want to post an answer using this information I will accept the answer and award you the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PAM is an interface for authentication tasks and it does not make the authentication by itself (for example it can delegate the authentication to a remote Kerberos or LDAP server, or to a local login system).

The configuration must be done at system level in `/etc/pam.d` or `/etc/pam.conf`. You should verify if your configuration is correct. For example, as your service name is "test", you probably need a file `/etc/pam.d/test`.

Or you can try to chose another service name in the `pam_start()` call. For example `"login"`.